# Are there any high level general purpose graphics libraries for julia?

Tags: graphics, julia

Julia libraries like 'GLAbstraction' are too low level for me. I need something like the 'Canvas API' for JavaScript in browsers. Are there any?

Comment: Is [Luxor](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Luxor.jl) what you're thinking of?

Comment: Just took a glance. It looks like a good one, and it also gave me couple other similar library links :D Thanks

Comment: What about Gtk.jl? It's interactive too.

Comment: If you found what you need, I suggest you write an answer to your own question. Ideally with all the libraries you found and their properties. (I won't, because I wasn't exactly sure about your requirements.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exhaustive list.  I put the first several links I was aware of.  I would start with `QML.jl` if you can.

Related discussions:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-for-gui-app/416
https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/viz/17

## Desktop Graphics Engines aka Desktop GUIs

If you search through the JuliaCon Videos from past years, you can find talks and walkthroughs for these packages.

I have a background in Qt and the Qt Libraries, and it is very general purpose.  QML is very friendly if you have a javascript background.  The KDE desktop in Linux is built around Qt.  Many desktop apps in general include Qt dlls, and use it as its backbone.

https://github.com/barche/QML.jl

And here is a youtube link or two about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AddbHe05yRg

https://github.com/barche/juliacon2020-qml - example code for the most recent talk on it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Bmp0I731Ak

Gtk has been around a long time and you can see it in use in GIMP and Gnome desktop in Linux.

https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl

The examples for Redux are mentioned in the PackageCompiler.jl video done recently.  These are more or less the React Native style apps, shipping a chromium browser and rendering a react environment as a desktop app.

https://github.com/Gnimuc/Redux.jl

## Interactive Plotting Libraries

There is a list of them here in the `Plots.jl` interface.  Plotting in Julia is a pretty big rabbit hole, and there are tons of options to look into.  Jupyter notebooks and the like with interactivity layered on them blurs the line between what is a GUI and what is just a plot.

http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/ecosystem/

https://juliaobserver.com/categories/Graphical%20Plotting

https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl

https://github.com/JuliaGL/GLVisualize.jl

https://github.com/JuliaGizmos/Interact.jl

https://github.com/plotly/Dash.jl

## Web Frameworks

https://genieframework.com/

https://github.com/JuliaGizmos/Interact.jl

https://github.com/plotly/Dash.jl